# Which is a better print resolution 2400 x 2400 DPI or 1200 X 4800 DPI

Tags: resolution, print-production, dpi, ppi

What is the difference in print resolution 2400 X 2400 DPI and 1200 X 4800 DPI. Is on better than the other if so how do you measure it

Comment: So you **really** mean "DPI" or are you asking about pixels and on-screen resolutions as they relate to printed images?

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell. In the end, theoretically, they both print a dot of the same area, but different shape.

There could be some additional aspects like paper absorption that could make a difference in how the dots are perceived. But this is just an assumption.

If you are choosing between two printers with the exact same specs except for this resolution, I would go for the 2400x2400 DPI, because, potentially the higher 4800 injectors can be blocked more easily.

But I would look for different parameters to choose from, like color, the number of inks, the overall look of the print, cost.

Answer (score 0):

The first value is usually Dots Per Inch in the X axis, and the second is amount in the Y axis (but I've seen someone stating the first value is vertical and second is horizontal but I guess it depend on position of paper[?]).
So in the printing process the 2,4k x 2,4k would have same amount of dots in the "rows" and "columns".
In the second case (I assume it's laser printer) there could be visible lines. Lines that are created form the fact the rows line would be created by software (so how much ink can stick to paper) while the column would be technical dependant on how precise the roller can move the paper for next row to be "inked".

Regarding the question "is one better than the other" is fall down to use. For printing photos, pictures the firs one would be better. The ink and dots placement would be more unified on the whole piece of paper.
The second printer would be better for printing technical stuff (I think) like plans or maps (maybe text) that require to be more consistent in one "longer" axis of the print.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, 4800 dots translates to more detail, but there will probably not be a noticeable difference unless you're doing microprinting. 1200 dpi provides a lot of printed detail, and 2400 is probably above the threshold of what the human eye can detect. Printing at 4800 dpi is probably overkill in that regard. If you don't notice a visible difference, you will probably save RIP time (and have better quality gradients) with a lower dpi.

Answer (score -2):

**There is *no* comparison**.

2400x2400px @ 300dpi = 8x8 inch print image

1200x4800px @ 300dpi = 4x16 inch print image

Neither is "better". They are completely different proportioned images.

Which one may work better for your needs, only you can determine.

---

To see print sizes..

Just do the math...

- 2400px ÷ 300ppi = 8 (8 inches)
- 1200px ÷ 300ppi = 4 (4 inches)
- 4800px ÷ 300pi = 16 (16 inches)

Or, if you avoid math....

- open a new document in Photoshop at 2400x2400px and 72ppi
- Once the new document is created chose `Image > Image size` from the menu
- When the Image Size dialog appears **uncheck** `Resample` and enter 300 into the `Resolution` field
- The width and height fields will update to show the new dimensions at that resolution.

---

You could *possibly* get a 10x10" and a 5x20" image if you use 240ppi. 240ppi is *sometimes* acceptable for print projects. Check with the print provider first though.

Comment: It looks like you're confusing DPI and PPI. Some printers have mismatched X-to-Y dpi output capabilities.

Comment: Or I'm correct and the question is incorrectly using "DPI" when it should be using "PPI". While imagesetters can easily hit 2400 or 4800 DPI.. it's *exceptionally rare* for the average user to ask about those. I merely chose to believe DPI was being used incorrectly in the question.